Raspberry pi Cool-Retro-Term permissions with python
I'm trying to run a python file in Cool-retro-term on my raspberry pi 4B, RASPBERRY PI OS FULL(32-BIT), but every time I try to open it, it says i don't have permission. I've solved this on my Mac but that required me giving it full disc access and changing the permission is the info tab. But I'm not sure how to do any of that on raspberry pi.
I've tried using chmod o+x main.py and even the directory to it but it keeps saying "No such file or directory".

I fixed it, I moved my file to my username folder and ran:
ls -l

to find the file's permissions then:
chmod +x filename.py

which added execute permissions, allowing me to run the program successfully in terminal and 'Cool-Retro-Term'.
